# XGBoost built-in best cut off calculation method (Youden's J Statistic or Euclidean Distance)

Tags: python, xgboost

How does the XGBoost classifier model calculate the best cutoff and return the predicted class?
I found out that there are 2 ways to calculate it.

Is it Youden's J Statistic or is it Euclidean Distance?

```
y_pred\_ = final_model.predict(apa_prepared_val)
```